# Calendario ng i18 a formato españa

Tags: angular, visual-studio, calendar, primeng, ng

Debo formatear el calendario de prime NG al formato de España, en el que las semanas comienzan en lunes, originalmente el calendario en primeNg está en formato americano.

```
export const CALENDER_CONFIG_ES = {
    firstDayOfWeek: 1,
    dayNames: ['Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado', 'Domingo'],
    dayNamesShort: ['L', 'M', 'X', 'J', 'V', 'S', 'D'],
    dayNamesMin: ['L', 'M', 'X', 'J', 'V', 'S', 'D'],
    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre',
        'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['E', 'F', 'Mz', 'Ab', 'My', 'Jn', 'Jl', 'Ag', 'S', 'O', 'N', 'D'],
    today: 'Hoy',
    clear: 'Reiniciar',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    weekHeader: 'Semana'
}
```

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 3):

Te aconsejo usar `@ngx-translate`

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core --save
npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader --save
```

1. Importas el Modulo en tu app.module.ts

```
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core'
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader'
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";


export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, './assets/i18n/', '.json')
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
       TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    })
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

2. Defines tu lenguaje por defecto para la aplicación en este caso `español`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
       TranslateModule.forRoot({
          defaultLanguage: 'es',
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    })
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3. Creas en tu carpeta `src/assets/i18n` un archivo `es.json` con esta estructura.

```
{
  "primeng": {
    "startsWith": "Comienza con",
    "contains": "Contiene",
    "notContains": "No contiene",
    "endsWith": "Termina con",
    "equals": "Igual",
    "notEquals": "No igual",
    "noFilter": "No filtrar",
    "lt": "Menor que",
    "lte": "Menor o igual a",
    "gt": "Mayor que",
    "gte": "Mayor o igual a",
    "is": "Es",
    "isNot": "No es",
    "before": "Antes",
    "after": "Despues",
    "dateIs": "La fecha es",
    "dateIsNot": "La fecha no es",
    "dateBefore": "La fecha es anterior",
    "dateAfter": "La fecha es despues",
    "clear": "Limpiar",
    "apply": "Aplicar",
    "matchAll": "Coincidir con todos",
    "matchAny": "Coincidir con cualquiera",
    "addRule": "Adicionar regla",
    "removeRule": "Eliminar regla",
    "accept": "Si",
    "reject": "No",
    "choose": "Seleccionar",
    "upload": "Subir",
    "cancel": "Cancelar",
    "dayNames": ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"],
    "dayNamesShort": ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mier", "Jue", "Vie", "Sab"],
    "dayNamesMin": ["Do", "Lu", "Ma", "Mi", "Ju", "Vi", "Sa"],
    "monthNames": ["enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", " diciembre"],
    "monthNamesShort": ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"],
    "dateFormat": "dd/mm/yy",
    "today": "Hoy",
    "weekHeader": "Semana",
    "weak": "Débil",
    "medium": "Medio",
    "strong": "Fuerte",
    "passwordPrompt": "Ingrese una contraseña",
    "emptyMessage": "No se encontraron resultados",
    "emptyFilterMessage": "No se encontraron resultados"
  }
}
```

4. En el componente donde vas a traducir los textos de primeNG `calendar` `filtros` `upload file` entre otros.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

import {TranslateService} from "@ngx-translate/core";
import {PrimeNGConfig} from "primeng/api";

import esLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/es'

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styles: [],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
    param = {value: 'world'};

calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    locale: esLocale,
     };

    // Importas el servicio en el constructor
    constructor(private primengConfig: PrimeNGConfig, private translateService: TranslateService) { }

   //Luego llamas al idioma seleccionado

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.translateChange('es')
  }

  translateChange(lang: string) {
    this.translateService.use(lang)
    this.translateService.get('primeng').subscribe((res) => this.primengConfig.setTranslation(res))
  }
}
```

Puedes definir varios idiomas para tu aplicación creando ficheros `.json` con los diferentes idiomas usando las mismas llaves. Si quieres hacer interactivo los idiomas debes llamar los que quieres que se usen el `constructor` de esta manera.

```
constructor(translateService: TranslateService) {
  this.translateService.addLangs(['en', 'es', 'fr', 'pt'])
}
```

Y luego implementar la interacción llamando el método `translateChange(lang: string) {}`

Espero que te sirva este procedimiento que permite hacer una aplicación multilenguaje